# Cannot read JSON file: "JSON text did not start with array or object"

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am parsing a remote JSON file to read and return an `NSDictionary` but am getting the error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

the following is my Swift code for parsing the JSON:

```
//---This is where I'm parsing the file--//
getJSON("https://www.dropbox.com/s/sx57tx3pwwffbly/Destination.json?dl=0")




func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSDictionary? {

    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!)!

    do {
        if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
            return jsonResult
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error.description)")
    }

    return nil
}
```

below is my JSON file

```
{ "results": [
{
    "Country": "AUS",
    "Name": "Byron Bay",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:41:45.275Z",
    "objectId": "2GcIpJRdhR",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:41:49.379Z"
},
{
    "Country": "ITA",
    "Name": "Florence",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:38:46.581Z",
    "objectId": "3HQMfF0Qlw",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:38:49.128Z"
},
{
    "Country": "AUS",
    "Name": "Adelaide",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:41:30.147Z",
    "objectId": "60wG6lyp2P",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:41:32.707Z"
},
{
    "Country": "GRC",
    "Name": "Santorini",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:40:07.472Z",
    "objectId": "8nVQ3RQK80",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:40:11.595Z"
},
{
    "Country": "AUS",
    "Name": "Hobart",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-30T00:43:11.225Z",
    "objectId": "ATggTTYcDl",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-30T00:43:17.625Z"
},
{
    "Country": "AUS",
    "Name": "Perth",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:41:36.415Z",
    "objectId": "CxQWRcJHA2",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:41:40.629Z"
},
{
    "Country": "ITA",
    "Name": "Venice",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:38:52.993Z",
    "objectId": "CzF8b6oH4I",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:38:55.851Z"
},
{
    "Country": "Aus",
    "Name": "Newcastle",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-30T23:13:06.695Z",
    "objectId": "EXbIGKcx0E",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-30T23:13:09.490Z"
},
{
    "Country": "ITA",
    "Name": "Pisa",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:39:48.342Z",
    "objectId": "HDwfPh3nC4",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:39:50.968Z"
},
{
    "Country": "ESP",
    "Name": "Barcelona",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:35:35.777Z",
    "objectId": "M2cVQGkoA9",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:35:49.540Z"
},
{
    "Country": "ITA",
    "Name": "Cinque Terre",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:39:34.556Z",
    "objectId": "NVabusFOzM",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:39:36.820Z"
},
{
    "Country": "AUS",
    "Name": "Sydney",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:35:15.984Z",
    "objectId": "PLqYdubhnB",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:35:23.837Z"
},
{
    "Country": "GRC",
    "Name": "Zakynthos",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:40:24.280Z",
    "objectId": "QgihbSfUo7",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:40:28.381Z"
},
{
    "Country": "ITA",
    "Name": "Rome",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:38:12.670Z",
    "objectId": "SEThamOY2N",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:38:15.502Z"
},
{
    "Country": "ITA",
    "Name": "Messina",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:39:25.597Z",
    "objectId": "XRb07EF1Tv",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:39:28.159Z"
},
{
    "Country": "GRC",
    "Name": "Athens",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:38:21.915Z",
    "objectId": "XS4gvYTJO4",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:38:42.682Z"
},
{
    "Country": "AUS",
    "Name": "Darwin",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-30T23:13:39.088Z",
    "objectId": "Xu0J2tbyfi",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-30T23:13:41.076Z"
},
{
    "Country": "AUS",
    "Name": "Sunshine Coast",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-30T00:43:47.810Z",
    "objectId": "XuUX7eYO2R",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-30T00:43:50.529Z"
},
{
    "Country": "ITA",
    "Name": "Milan",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:38:02.137Z",
    "objectId": "YeqqW7IBwR",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:38:05.802Z"
},
{
    "Country": "AUS",
    "Name": "Gold Coast",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-25T22:52:58.169Z",
    "objectId": "cuVrgPuLxy",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-30T00:43:21.778Z"
},
{
    "Country": "AUS",
    "Name": "Cairns",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-30T23:12:49.327Z",
    "objectId": "cxf8wcvsX6",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-30T23:12:53.120Z"
},
{
    "Country": "ESP",
    "Name": "Madrid",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:40:42.536Z",
    "objectId": "fuk8y4owDC",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:40:45.618Z"
},
{
    "Country": "GRC",
    "Name": "Mykonos",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:39:57.422Z",
    "objectId": "gbXvwPpS41",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:40:02.912Z"
},
{
    "Country": "GRC",
    "Name": "Ios",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:40:14.962Z",
    "objectId": "hiWu6gKdJ0",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:40:18.221Z"
},
{
    "Country": "ESP",
    "Name": "Costa Brava",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:37:50.021Z",
    "objectId": "kg9CrSzxM3",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:37:54.461Z"
},
{
    "Country": "AUS",
    "Name": "Canberra",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-25T22:53:28.205Z",
    "objectId": "s0EbEsucbN",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-30T00:43:19.336Z"
},
{
    "Country": "AUS",
    "Name": "Terrigal",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:41:54.467Z",
    "objectId": "uvyotYvZjw",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:42:04.227Z"
},
{
    "Country": "AUS",
    "Name": "Brisbane",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:41:12.373Z",
    "objectId": "w8zcIGffqI",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:41:18.939Z"
},
{
    "Country": "AUS",
    "Name": "Melbourne",
    "createdAt": "2015-11-03T00:41:22.251Z",
    "objectId": "zQH8uI9RkM",
    "updatedAt": "2015-11-03T00:41:26.004Z"
}
] }
```

I have read up on this issue and the main problem that my error suggests is the format of the JSON file meaning the error states is could not find a valid start to the JSON document or an array within the JSON document.

Will understand down votes for duplicate question but I have not found anything suitable to my situation. 
In short at the moment I want to read a remote JSON file and print it out. Later on however i would use the results to then store into CoreData model. All answers I have found for the later are not updated for swift 2.0

Comment: Somebody (deleted answer) mentioned that you should remove the outermost `{  }`. However, that doesn't seem to be what W3C recommends:  http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

Comment: @NicolasMiari that answer was quite wrong, the outermost `{}` is, in fact, necessary.

Comment: My 2 cent diagnosis: the file shown is *not* the text that is being parsed.

Comment: The blob you posted is valid. I suggest you print out the raw string you receive.

Comment: Indeed; OP could try to convert their `data` to `String` and `print()` it to the console, just to be sure.

Comment: @user2864740 I have edited my answer to show where the file is being parsed. I also printed the parameter 'urlToRequest' as has been suggested and it is still the right string.

Comment: @Kevin i did your suggestion and it is the correct string. Please see the edited question to see where i parse the string (url)

Comment: The url (https://www.dropbox.com/s/sx57tx3pwwffbly/Destination.json?dl=0) returns HTML, not JSON. Somebody owes me two pennies.

Comment: @user2864740 thats real odd. i must be storing it incorrectly then ? suggestions on how to retrieve the JSON as i uploaded it as a JSON file

Comment: Compare the URL with https://www.dropbox.com/s/sx57tx3pwwffbly/Destination.json?dl=1 (browse to both in a browser, or better, cURL both). Note how they do not return the same response. Check the response *also* under getJSON.

Comment: @user2864740 the url in the comment where you said it returns html takes me to a dropbox page displaying the JSON whereas the url in the comment before this downloads the JSON file upon clicking it.

Comment: @Vince Exactly: that is the *same* URL in the posted code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98053/discussion-between-vince-and-user2864740).

Comment: Would be great to discuss this with you further ^^ @user2864740

Comment: @user2864740: What may confuse people is that the URL downloads html that _displays what the JSON data should look like_, but with line numbers etc.

Comment: Agreed @gnasher729 it got me. What i notice also is the parameter difference between the URL I gave and the URL user2864740 gave me instead. That is the '=0' or '=1'. Im assuming these are true/false values that the server determines whether to display or provide a download for URL dependent on the value parsed as the parameter. Does this have any truth to it ?

Answer (score -1):

It looks OK to me. JSON file attached if working properly

```
if let a = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: .AllowFragments) {
    print(a)
}
```

I used just strign and 'dataUsingEncoding' method but it shoudn't be any problem with this too

```
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("File", ofType: "txt")!) {

        if let a = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments) {
            print(a)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, I don't know how that came - I didn't even look at this answer, I just saw today that apparently there was a downvote done by me ?!?